# Nest Update By Id That Is Auto Generated By ElasticDb

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I used Nest 6.X framework to manage ElasticSearch with c# At there I shared the result of nest query.

The c# code like this

```
_elasticSearchDb.Update(DocumentPath<myElasticType>.Id("Cq2jmGgB5bes6sABU8NP"), u => u.DocAsUpsert(true).Doc(myObject));
```

I want to update a document in an index by documentId that is generated by Elasticsearch as automaticly.

At this point, I don't have any problem.

Now think that I have 1 replica and 5 shard on elasticdb.

I have a few doubt when I want to execute this update progress. For example per day I send request to elasticsearch in different time as total 5000 request at the end of the day.

At this point, Can I have any performance problem on elastic db?

**Here is the Elaastic Raw Query Request and response that genarated by Nest**

> Note: myElasticIndex and myElasticType terms used as dummny

```
Valid NEST response built from a successful low level call on POST: /myElasticIndex/myElasticType/Cq2jmGgB5bes6sABU8NP/_update
# Audit trail of this API call:
 - [1] HealthyResponse: Node: http://localhost:9200/ Took: 00:00:00.0189528
# Request:
{
  "doc_as_upsert": true,
  "doc": {
    "person": "Eyup Can ARSLAN",
    "recordDate": "2019-01-29",
    "field3": "field3 data",
    "field4": "field 4 data"
  }
}


# Response:
{
  "_index": "myElasticIndex",
  "_type": "myElasticType",
  "_id": "Cq2jmGgB5bes6sABU8NP",
  "_version": 3,
  "result": "noop",
  "_shards": {
    "total": 0,
    "successful": 0,
    "failed": 0
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the documents that you wish to upsert, and their ids, you can send them in batches with the Bulk API

```
var client = new ElasticClient();

var updates = new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    { "id1", new { foo = "bar" } },
    { "id2", new { foo = "baz" } }
};

var bulkResponse = client.Bulk(b => 
{
    b.Index("my_index").Type("my_type");

    foreach(var update in updates)
    {
        b.Update<object>(u => u
            .Id(update.Key)
            .DocAsUpsert()
            .Doc(update.Value)
        );
    }   

    return b;
});
```

The `TValue` generic parameter of updates can be your POCO type. This sends the following request

```
POST http://localhost:9200/my_index/my_type/_bulk
{"update":{"_id":"id1"}}
{"doc_as_upsert":true,"doc":{"foo":"bar"}}
{"update":{"_id":"id2"}}
{"doc_as_upsert":true,"doc":{"foo":"baz"}}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, What do you think about 5000   update request that is total request in different time for per day.   By the way imagine that your ElasticDb has 2 million records

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the question is?